# Chrome extension: How to detect if a different chrome extension is open?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension, I want to detect when another chrome extensions pop up window is open. Let's say my extension is named A and there is another chrome extension named B. I want code to execute on A when B is opened.

Is it also possible for A to interact with B's popup menu? As in A detects that B is open, so it will fill in input forms and click buttons?

Comment: Generally not possible. You can only do it on a local machine by starting chrome with a special command line.

Comment: @wOxxOm can you link me documentation?